# Focus Popup Input Field

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, lightbox

I am trying to focus the username input when a button it pressed.
I have tried autofocus but that doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

I don't really want to use javascript for this (haven't yet!) but I know I might have to.

```
<a class="button" href="#popup1" accesskey="r"><img class="access" src="images/login.png" /></a>


<div id="popup1" class="overlay">
    <div class="popup">
        <div class="popup_header">
            <h2>Log In</h2>
                <a class="close" href="#" accesskey="w">×</a>
        </div>

        <div class="content">
            <section>
                <ul class="input-list cred clearfix">
                <form action="login.php" method="POST">
                    <li>
                        <input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password">
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Sign In">
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
        </div>      
    </div>
```

Comment: That's not possible without using JS because autofocus works only on the page initial load unless been added manually

Comment: Well then how would I do this with javascript?

Comment: use .focus() on the input when the popup is shown. if needed I can add the whole solution.

Comment: Can you please? I am new to javascript. I have tried            username.focus(); //sets focus to element
var val = this.username.value; //store the value of the element
this.username.value = ''; //clear the value of the element
this.username.value = val; //set that value back.  // JavaScript Document                                       But That didn't work

Comment: try this .. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_html_blur

Answer (score 0):

According to your markup for popup I could suggest this method for showing the popup and focusing the input (in this case only the first type text input):

```
$('a').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var target = $(this).attr('href');
    $(target).show();
    $($('input[type=text]', target).get(0)).focus();
})
```

Comment: How do I implement this into my html?

Comment: use a script tag and put the js code above into the script tags. `<script>-- put the js here --</script>`. Also do not forget to load jquery script before the above code in your html. you code use this one `<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.min.js"></script>`

Comment: I'm sorry for asking.. but where would be the best place to put the script?

Comment: Usually before the place where `body` tag is being closed. so before `</body>`. by the way if my solution helped you please accept it as the right answer.

Comment: Thank you. I appreciate it. Unfortunately this did not work in my case :( It made my hyperlink inactive

Comment: That is because of `$('a')` tag which is targeting all anchor tags in the page. instead use a class `$('a.button')`. It would be really better if you use a specific class like `popup-link` on the anchor tags that only show the popup. in this case I assume the `.button` class is doing such duty for you.

Comment: This still caused the same situation.

Comment: It would be really better if you use a specific class like `popup-link` on the anchor tags that only show the popup. in this case I assume the `.button` class is doing such duty for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
autofocus works in IE10+, Chrome, FireFox - please test in other browsers  
but it works only on page load.
<input type="text" name="username" placeholder="Username" autofocus/>
Non supported browsers require JavaScript/Jquery to provide a focus on page
load.
focus on button click always require JavaScript/Jquery.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

$("#buttonid").click(function(){

```
//put an id to your username inputbox
$("#username").focus();
```

});